# The operation couldn't be completed IDETemplateParseError error1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have made a simple program that gets a users input, displays it in a table, inputs are saved to core data so that the next time the application is loaded, the table shows the saved data.

However, I am getting a build-time error which is Uncategorized. I've been stuck for a while and I can't find anything online.

The error is: The operation couldn't be completed. (IDEFoundation .IDETemplateParseError error 1.)

All I have at the moment in my .xcdatamodeId is one entity called Places and one attribute within that entity called locationVisited.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There is mistake of giving name of .xcdatamodeld. Remove white space from file name and retry for build. I hope it will help you.

Comment: What do you mean by whitespaces, I have no white spaces in the file name, its got underscores

Answer (score 1):

Remove white space from your .xcdatamodeId file name. It's help for successfully build app.

Comment: I have no white spaces, I got underscores for spaces yet the error remains :(